# non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family

Tags: r

I'm having some issues with a `glmer` model.

My dataset is composed by a continuous dependent variable (y), that goes from 200 to 2000. The measure is taken in millisecond (ms). I have three predictors, A, B, C. The first two predictors have two levels, A1, A2, B1, B2 and the last one has three levels C1, C2 and C3.

I check the distribution of my dependent variable (y) with

```
descdist(mydata$y)
```

[image: descdist_image]

from the image I uploaded I assumed that my dependend variable is distributed as a gamma distribution.

I tried also with

```
fit.gamma <- fitdist(mydata$RT, distr = "gamma", method = "mme")
```

and when I plot the fit it seems to fit good

[image: Fit_gamma]

So I tried a `glmer` with `family=Gamma`:

```
model<-glmer(y~A+B+C+A*B*+(1|Subject), family= Gamma(), data=mydata)
```

but I received the error message:

```
Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : 
  non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family
```

All my value are positive as it is possible to see from the image Fit_gamma.

So, my question is why do I receive that message, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you rule out there are no *y* values that are no values at zero (or a little under)?  Something like `summary(mydata$y)`.  Judging from the graphs, they can't be too far less than 0.

Comment: Your histogram makes it look like you might have a/some 0 values.  A zero is a "non-positive value".